# Give a bijective proof to show that the number of ways presesnts can be distributed?

Tags: combinatorics

I am asked the following:

We want to distribute $n$ presents to $k$ children. We are told that we are supposed to give child $1$ $a_{1}$ presents, child $2$ $a_{2}$ presents,$\ldots$, child $k$ $a_{k}$ presents. 
(Assume that $a_{1}+\ldots+a_{k}=n$).

Recall that $\binom{n}{a_{1},\ldots,a_{k}}$ is defined to be the sequences of length $n$ with $a_{i} i$'s, for $1\leq i\leq k$.

Give a bijective proof to show that the number of ways these presents can be distributed is also counted by $\binom{n}{a_{1},\ldots,a_{k}}$.

---

This is from my first homework assignment for the quarter, however we haven't talked too much about bijective proofs.
I'm unsure what we should consider for a bijection, more specifically the mapping.
Do I want to consider the set of children, $C=\{1,\ldots ,k\}$, and the set of  presents, denoted by $P=\{a_{1}, \ldots ,a_{k}\}$; take the power set of both $P$ and $C$, then define a function $\varphi:2^{C}\rightarrow2^{P}$? What should the mapping be?

Any push is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: You want to show a bijection between the set of sequences as described in the definition of the multinomial numbers and the set of way to distribute the presents.

Comment: Multinomial numbers being of the form $\binom{n}{a_{1},\ldots,a_{k}}=\frac{n!}{a_{1}!\cdot \ldots\cdot a_{k}!}$? Can you clarify further?

Comment: The multinomial numbers count sequences of length n with $a_i$ entries being $i$. You want to show that the set of all such sequences is in bijective correspondence with the set of ways to distribute presents. This will show that the multinomial coefficients also counts the number of ways to distribute presents.

Answer (score 1):

You could count the number of ways to distribute presents directly and show that this is exactly the multinomial combination. But if you are looking for a "bijective" proof, you, as SE318 suggests, want to create a bijection between the set of sequences of length $n$ with $a_i$ $i$'s and the set of ways to distribute the presents. You're initial inclination is interesting, but I don't think it will get you anywhere because you should be interested in a bijection between the previously mentioned sets. Most of the time with proofs like these, you don't want to rigorously define a function and prove that it's a bijection, but give a "transformation" that shows that these problems are the same and so have the same solution. Let me show you:

Let $A$ be the number of sequences of length $n$ with $a_i$ $i$'s and let $B$ be the number of ways to distribute these presents.

Fix the order of the presents, $p_i, \ldots, p_n$. Given a sequence of length $n$ with $a_i$ $i$'s, let an $i$ in the $j$th spot of the sequence mean that we give present $p_j$ to kid $i$. This is valid for any sequence (you should check this), so $A \geq B$.

Similarly, given a way to distribute present you can derive a sequence just as above. This is valid for any present distribution (check), so $A \leq B$. Thus we've created a bijection between the two problems, but haven't talked about formal functions.